# insert AssignmentOperator ArrayInitializer error

Tags: java, assignment-operator, array-initialization

I am learning java but stuck with this issue, I am writing a simple code but this error is throwing up again
Can some one help me with what wrong i am doing?

```
public String alarmClock(int day, boolean vacation) {
if (day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
  if (vacation = true) {
      return "10:00";
  }
  else (vacation = false) {return "7:00";}
 }
else {
  if (vacation = true) {
      return "off";
  }
  else (vacation = false) {return "10:00";}
 }
}
```

the error which it is giving is-

```
Error:  else (vacation = false) {return "7:00";}
                      ^
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator ArrayInitializer" to complete ArrayInitializerAssignement
```

What the output i want is this -

```
alarmClock(1, false) → "7:00"
alarmClock(5, false) → "7:00"
alarmClock(0, false) → "10:00"
```

I know this may be simple but i am just new to java so i want to learn this.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a condition use == (comparison), not = (assignment) :

change

```
if (vacation = true)
```

to

```
if (vacation == true)
```

or even better

```
    if (vacation)
```

Beside that, `else (vacation = false)` is invalid syntax, and you don't need it anyway. Just write `else`.

```
if (day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
  if (vacation) {
      return "10:00";
  } else {
      return "7:00";
  }
} else {
  if (vacation) {
      return "off";
  } else {
      return "10:00";
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i know that  else (vacation = false) is invalid, i have tried with only else, in that case the out is not correct..

Comment: Thanks  (vacation == true) worked, amazed that it was so simple !!